# expected type-specifier and cannot convert ‘int*’ in initialization

Tags: c++, class, oop, namespaces

I have a large amount of code, so I have tried to only include the relevant parts of the code here

My cpp files compiled with no problems when they were included in another cpp file.

I have another file called. This compiled fine before, until I tried to include the files above in

I get undefined reference errors, even though they were defined in the cpp file

What is going on? Is there a linkage error? Do I need to make changes in the makefile?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after the class.

Comment: oh, the actual class has a semicolon after it. I just forgot to include it when I tried to modify its contents to post it in the question

Comment: OK. What other differences are there?

Comment: Why are you using `Asp::Asp(input)` ? Shouldn't that be either `Asp* asp = new Asp(input)` (because of your using clause) or a full resolved `ASP:Asp* asp = ASP::Asp(input)` including the namespace ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, why would `new ASp::ASp(input);` be considered an `int*`?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
ASp* asp = new ASp(input);
```

works for me. Not sure why using

```
ASp* asp = new ASp::ASp(input);
```

is a problem. Need to dig further to find out.

**Update**

The same problem was addressed at [using declarations in main (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726422/using-declarations-in-main-c). The tool chain for that question is MS Visual Studio. The answers there point out the same problem but there is no explanation of why `new Asp::Asp(input);` would be of type `int*`. The error message reported by the OP appears to be a `g++` specific error message.