# Using injected class name to invoke member functions

Tags: c++

At [Calling a static method by repeating the object name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152477/calling-a-static-method-by-repeating-the-object-name?newsletter=1&nlcode=342486%7c291c), I see the following code.

```
struct foo {
  static foo& instance() {
    static foo f;
    return f;
  }
};
```

And

```
foo::foo::foo::instance();
```

works fine.

However, at [expected type-specifier and cannot convert ‘int*’ in initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049446/expected-type-specifier-and-cannot-convert-int-in-initialization), I see the following code:

```
namespace ASP
{
    class ASp
    {
        public:
            ASp();
            ASp(FILE* fp);  
    };
}
```

But

```
using namespace ASP;
ASp* asp = new ASp::ASp();
```

fails to compile in g++ 4.8.2 and Visual Studio 2010.

g++ reports:

```
error: expected type-specifier
 ASp* asp = new ASp::ASp();
```

Visual Studio reports:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier '{ctor}'
```

Why does injected class name work for the first case and not for the second case?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know whether asp denotes a namespace or a class. Use asp::asp instead.

Comment: @user1535111, The namespace is `ASP`, with an uppercase `P`. The class name is `ASp`, with a lowercase `p`.

Comment: My mistake! But both examples cannot compile under vs2015 preview and give the same errors! With typename added to the 2nd example, both are fine under gcc!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think GCC provides a rather useful hint:

```
error: expected type-specifier
```

The `new` operator expects a *type name* immediately afterwards, not a constructor name.

The expression `ASp::ASp` can refer to either the constructor of the type or the type itself.  However, C++ has rules on how this ambiguity is resolved: in your case it defaults to the constructor, not the type.  In order to force this to be resolved as a type, you must prefix it with `typename` (thanks ooga!), `struct`, or `class` (or access its member using `::` like in your first example):

```
using namespace ASP;
ASp* asp = new class ASp::ASp();
```

Comment: You could also use `typename`.