# Using delete[] (Heap corruption) when implementing operator+=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, new-operator, delete-operator

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now, and I'm at my wit's end.  I would surely appreciate it if someone could tell me when I'm doing wrong.

I have written a simple class to emulate basic functionality of strings.  The class's members include a character pointer **data** (which points to a dynamically created char array) and an integer **strSize** (which holds the length of the string, sans terminator.)

Since I'm using **new** and **delete**, I've implemented the copy constructor and destructor.  My problem occurs when I try to implement the **operator+=**.  The LHS object builds the new string correctly - I can even print it using cout - but the problem comes when I try to deallocate the data pointer in the destructor:  I get a "Heap Corruption Detected after normal block" at the memory address pointed to by the **data** array the destructor is trying to deallocate.

Here's my complete class and test program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Class to emulate string
class Str {
public:

    // Default constructor
    Str(): data(0), strSize(0) { }

    // Constructor from string literal
    Str(const char* cp) {
        data = new char[strlen(cp) + 1];
        char *p = data;
        const char* q = cp;
        while (*q)
            *p++ = *q++;
        *p = '\0';
        strSize = strlen(cp);
    }

    Str& operator+=(const Str& rhs) {
        // create new dynamic memory to hold concatenated string
        char* str = new char[strSize + rhs.strSize + 1];

        char* p = str;                  // new data
        char* i = data;                 // old data
        const char* q = rhs.data;       // data to append

        // append old string to new string in new dynamic memory
        while (*p++ = *i++) ;
        p--;
        while (*p++ = *q++) ;
        *p = '\0';

        // assign new values to data and strSize
        delete[] data;
        data = str;
        strSize += rhs.strSize;
        return *this;
    }


    // Copy constructor
    Str(const Str& s)
    {
        data = new char[s.strSize + 1];
        char *p = data;
        char *q = s.data;
        while (*q)
            *p++ = *q++;
        *p = '\0';
        strSize = s.strSize;
    }

    // destructor
    ~Str() { delete[] data;  }

    const char& operator[](int i) const { return data[i]; }
    int size() const { return strSize; }

private:
    char *data;
    int strSize;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Str& s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i)
        os << s[i];
    return os;
}


// Test constructor, copy constructor, and += operator
int main()
{
    Str s = "hello";        // destructor  for s works ok
    Str x = s;              // destructor for x works ok
    s += "world!";          // destructor for s gives error
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Accelerated C++ problem 12-1.

Comment: This begs for a few obvious questions - or for the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following chunk of code makes p pointed beside the array.

```
while (*p++ = *q++) ;
*p = '\0';
```

Better (and safe) solution you have used in copy constructor:

```
while (*q)
    *p++ = *q++;
*p = '\0';
```

Comment: Actually, it should work if he'd just remove the `*p = '\0'` in the first example.  `while (*p++ = *q++)` will copy the zero character and then stop.  (I'd say he should stop doing it this way and use stuff from `string.h`, eg. `memcpy`.  A more C++ person [as opposed to a C person] would also say he shouldn't bother with `char *` at all and suggest `std::string`.)

Comment: @asveikau: You're right on spot with `*p = '\0'`. But if this is an exercise, he should do it manually. (Although I agree that one could question why he is using `std::strlen()`, but not `std::strcpy()`.)

Comment: @sbi: colleague, I can also provide my own list of objections to this listing, but my experience shows, that people mostly asks about help (me too) in trivial cases.

Comment: One more thing - why didn't my program crash at this point, when it first tries to write to unallocated memory?  It doesn't actually crash until delete[] is called in the destructor.

Comment: @Darel, it is concerned with process of memory management. According to flat model of Intel it is too expensive ask OS (linux or windows) allocate memory when you need 10 bytes. That is why all tools (compilers, CLR ...) reserves large chunks, reducing calls number to OS memory manager. If your memory error touches pre-allocated chunk, exception wouldn't be raised. If you try to access non managed OS memory (e.g: 0xCCCCCCCC) then exception is raised. At last about delete: this operator tries to support linked list of memory blocks, since you have damage this block exception was raised.

Answer (score 3):

There are already a bunch of good answers here, but it's worth plugging [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) as a tool for solving exactly this sort of problem.  If you have access to a *nix box, the Valgrind tools can be a real lifesaver.

Just to show you, here's what I got when compiling and running your program through it:

```
% g++ -g -o test test.cpp
% valgrind ./test
==2293== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2293== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2293== Using Valgrind-3.5.0-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2293== Command: ./test
==2293==
==2293== Invalid write of size 1
==2293==    at 0x8048A9A: Str::operator+=(Str const&) (test.cpp:36)
==2293==    by 0x8048882: main (test.cpp:82)
==2293==  Address 0x42bc0dc is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==2293==    at 0x4025024: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:258)
==2293==    by 0x8048A35: Str::operator+=(Str const&) (test.cpp:26)
==2293==    by 0x8048882: main (test.cpp:82)
==2293== 
helloworld!
hello
==2293== 
==2293== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2293==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2293==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 31 bytes allocated
==2293== 
==2293== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2293== 
==2293== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2293== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 6)
%
```

You can see that it pinpointed the lines that the other answers here pointed out (near line 36).

Comment: Impressive... I didn't know such tools existed!  But my main workstation is a Windows box :(  I did some searching here on SO, but didn't find any (free) tool as good as this for Visual Studio.  I may have to set up a linux VM just to take advantage of such advanced debugging tools.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (*p++ = *i++) ; // the last iteration is when i is one past the end
// i is two past the end here -- you checked for a 0, found it, then incremented past it
p--; //here you corrected for this
while (*p++ = *q++) ;// the last iteration is when p and q are one past the end
// p and q are two past the end here
// but you didn't insert a correction here
*p = '\0';  // this write is in unallocated memory
```

Use an idiom similar to what you used in the copy constructor:

```
while (*i) *p++ = *i++; //in these loops, you only increment if *i was nonzero
while (*q) *p++ = *q++;
*p = '\0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have two answers pointing at the specific error that made you trash the heap. Assuming this is ***homework*** or some other form of exercise (otherwise we'd all be yelling at you for writing your own string class), here's a few more things to chew on for you:

- If you feel the need to ***annotate*** the code, consider making it ***more expressive***.
  For example, instead of `char* p = str; // new data`, you could just write `char* new_data = str;`.
  Instead of `//do frgl`, followed by a chunk of code, you could just write `do_frgl();`. If the function is inlined, it makes no difference for the resulting code, but a lot of difference to readers of the code.
- Everyone including your header gets ***everything from namespace `std` dumped into the global namespace***. [That's not a good idea at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712076/2712125#2712125) I'd avoid including your header like the plague.
- Your constructors should initialize their class' members in ***initializer lists***.
- Your `Str::Str(const char*)` constructor calls `std::strlen()` twice for the same string.
  ***Application code*** should be ***as fast as needed***, ***library code***, on the other hand, where you don't know which application it ends in, should be ***as fast as possible***. You're writing library code.
- Could the `size()` member function ever return a ***negative value***? If not, why is it a signed integer?
- What would happen for this code: `Str s1, s2; s1=s2`?
- And what about this: `Str str("abc"); std::cout<<str[1];`

*(If anyone coming across this can think of more hints, feel free to expand this.)*

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  It's not homework per se; I'm a working professional learning C++ on my own time.  This came from "Accelerated C++" problem 12-1.

Comment: Ah, _Accelerated C++_, an excellent choice, although it has a steep learning curve. Be sure to check on the definitive C++ book list for your next C++ book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/.