# distance calculation error in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, using-directives, overload-resolution, name-lookup

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int square(int a){
    return a*a;
}
struct  Point{
    int x,y;

};
int distance (const  Point& a,const Point& b){
    int k=(int) sqrt((float)((a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x))+((a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)));
    return k;

}
int main(){

    vector<Point>a(10);
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        cin>>a[i].x>>a[i].y;
    }

    int s=0;
    int s1;
    int k=0; 
    for (int i=1;i<10;i++){

        s+=square(distance(a[0],a[i]));
    }
    for (int i=1;i<10;i++){
        s1=0;
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
            s1+=square(distance(a[i],a[j]));

            if (s1<s) {  s=s1; k=i;}

        }
    }
    cout<<k<<"Points are:";
    cout<<a[k].x;
    cout<<a[k].y;


    return 0;
}
```

i have following code  but here is list of errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: distance, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  distance.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(373): error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'Point'
1>          d:\c++_algorithms\distance\distance\distance.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Point'
1>          d:\c++_algorithms\distance\distance\distance.cpp(30) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(373): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iterator_category'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(373): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(373): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(373) : see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(373): error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(374): error C2039: 'value_type' : is not a member of 'Point'
1>          d:\c++_algorithms\distance\distance\distance.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Point'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(374): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'value_type'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(374): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(374): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(374) : see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(374): error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::value_type' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(375): error C2039: 'difference_type' : is not a member of 'Point'
1>          d:\c++_algorithms\distance\distance\distance.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Point'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(375): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'difference_type'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(375): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(375): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(375) : see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(375): error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(377): error C2039: 'pointer' : is not a member of 'Point'
1>          d:\c++_algorithms\distance\distance\distance.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Point'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(377): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'pointer'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(377): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(377): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::pointer' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(377) : see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::pointer'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(377): error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::pointer' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(378): error C2039: 'reference' : is not a member of 'Point'
1>          d:\c++_algorithms\distance\distance\distance.cpp(9) : see declaration of 'Point'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(378): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'reference'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(378): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(378): error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::reference' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(378) : see declaration of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::reference'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(378): error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::reference' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Iter=Point
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: 271 questions to date and still not able (or unwilling) to format code for readability ?

Comment: Ran the code through VS' auto-formatter.

Answer (score 26):

This is caused in part by your use of `using namespace std;`.

There is a function in the standard library, `std::distance`, that is used to compute the distance between two iterators into a container.  That function is being selected during overload resolution instead of your `distance` function.

If you don't use `using namespace std;`, you won't have this problem.  Your use of `using namespace std;` brings all of the names from the `std` namespace into the global namespace.  This is bad because there are a lot of common names in namespace `std` and it can cause convoluted issues during name lookup, as  you've discovered here.

In general, prefer not to use `using namespace`, especially not at file scope.  It's far easier and clearer in the long run to qualify each of the names that you want to use.

Comment: The Op will then need to use std::vector for the vector definition. (adding for completeness to try and pre-empt the next compiler error!)

Comment: +1, This is a great example post that shows the inherent problems with "using namespace xyz;" to save typing.

Comment: @winwaed: Another option would be `using std::vector;`

Comment: Why would overload resolution choose the `std::distance` template instead of the `distance` provided here?

Comment: Well, now I know why James was asking me about my old rant against `using namespace std;`. [Here it is.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879555/2880136#2880136) Note how [tsubasa also had trouble with `std::distance()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712076/2712125#2712125). Coincidence?

Comment: @Moo-Juice, it's not just for saving typing. I don't know about you, but I can understand `map<list<string>, set<list<string> > >` easily, but `std::map<std::list<std::string>, std::set<std::list<std::string> > >` just makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: @Shahbaz:  That is what `typedef`s are for.  That said, if you have a `std::map<std::list<std::string>, std::set<std::list<std::string> > >`, chances are you want to reconsider what you're doing.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, oh of course, but you still have to write that abomination down at least once. I don't argue that `using namespace std;` isn't bad. I had problem with it once myself, too. But I still prefer to keep my function names obviously distinct from anything that could be in `std` that `using namespace std;` wouldn't cause me problems.

Answer (score 5):

@James is right in that getting rid of `using namespace std` will make this problem go away.  But that's not *exactly* what the actual problem is.

The problem comes from the way names are resolved in C++.  C++ uses a very aggressive approach to resolving name lookups when resolving the names of free functions if no suitable class member was found.  This is called [Argument-dependent name lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (or ADL), sometimes referred to as Koenig lookup.  And at the same time, it is one of the things makes C++ so powerful, but also so deadly and confounding.

Here's the basic problem, simplified.

You call `vector::operator[]` which returns a `vector::reference` or a `vector::const_reference`.  You take this return value and call `distance()` unqualified.

Because `distance` wasn't found in and applicable class, ADL kicks in, which goes out and gets *too many potential matching names*.

ADL then goes through the list of candidates and picks "the best match".  In this case, the `reference` that `operator[]` returns is a closer match to the type expected by `std::distance` than by your `distance`, although both are compatible, so `std::distance` is selected.

Several ways to solve this problem:

1. Don't `using namespace std`. Instead, `using` just the peices you want.
2. Quantify explicitly which `distance` you refer to using the scope resolution operator: `::distance()`
3. Change `distance` to take pointers instead of `const &`.  This effectively turns off ADL.:

Example:

```
int distance(const Point* a,const Point* b)
s+=square(distance(&a[0],&a[1]));
```

Additional Resources:

["A Modest Proposal: Fixing ADL (revision 2)" by Herb Sutter](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2103.pdf)

Comment: Still don't get how a template can be a better match than a non-template. BTW, the vector is irrelevant and the error is the same if `a` is a plain array?