# Why does this program swap the values?

Tags: c++, swap, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I have the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

void swap(long a, long b)
{
    long temp;

    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x = 5, y = 3;
    cout << x ;
    cout << y << endl;

    swap(x, y);

    cout << x ;
    cout << y << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The program gives the output:

```
5 3

3 5
```

The program actually swaps the values!  Why is that? The parameters of the `swap()` are not pointers or references.

(I am using VS 2005)

Comment: Basically, this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712076/how-to-use-iterator-in-c/2712125#2712125, although you wouldn't know this unless you know the answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your `swap` function isn't being called at all.

One of the Standard Library includes that you have included is pulling in `<utility>`, which declares a function template named `swap` in the `std` namespace.  Since you are `using namespace std;`, that `swap` function is being brought into the global namespace and it is called instead.

---

Why is `std::swap` chosen instead of your `swap` function?  Your `swap` function takes two `long`s by value; to call that function, an integer promotion is required for each of the `int` arguments.

`std::swap` is a function template.  It takes two references to `T`, and when that function template is instantiated with `T = int`, both arguments are an exact match.  So, `std::swap` is a better match than your function and it is therefore selected during overload resolution.

---

This is one reason that `using namespace std;` is evil and should be avoided.  If you remove the using directive, your function will be the only function available and it will be called.

Comment: You can call you swap() by ::swap(x, y)

Answer (score 1):

Say `long` instead of `int`.

Your current code already has a better match for `swap`, so it avoids the implicit conversion to `long`, and instead uses the built-in `swap` from the STL.

On a side note, this ambiguity is somewhat solved using [overload sets](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/hijack.html) (also [here](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/function.html#overload-sets)) in the language D.