# In c++ if header is included why I got 'does not a name of type' error?

Tags: c++

I have `data.h`:

```
#ifndef DATA_H_INCLUDED
#define DATA_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class student{
    public:
        string id;
        int points [6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
};



#endif // DATA_H_INCLUDED
```

And I have `enor.h`:

```
#ifndef ENOR_H_INCLUDED
#define ENOR_H_INCLUDED
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "data.h"

using namespace std;

enum status{norm,abnorm};

class enor{
    public:
        /*some voids*/
        Student Current() const { return elem; }
        student elem;
    private:
       /*some voids*/
};


#endif // ENOR_H_INCLUDED
```

And I got `'Student' does not a name a type`, but why? I tried also if the `Student` calss is in `enor.h`, but also this error. how can I resolve this, and why is this?

Comment: This is because you failed to include a [mcve] in your question. It's also possible it's because [you have a bad C++ teacher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Uppercase/lowercase problem. You have defined a class named `student` but are trying to use `Student`.

Comment: As already mentioned, `using namespace std;` is bad, but doing that in a header is unacceptable. Please learn C++ from a good book, whatever you are doing now will not get you anywhere.

Comment: Please carefully read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/721269) which explains how `using namespace std;` can result in code whose behavior changes unpredictably. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712076/how-to-use-an-iterator/2712125) a case where just including your header could cause unrelated code to break while still compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a difference in your case for your `student` class:

1. `class student` - Lower case `s`
2. `Student Current() const` - Upper case `S`